# How to change font size in Spring tutorial windows in STS (Eclipse)?

Tags: eclipse, font-size, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Spring STS is based on Eclipse. It contains tutorials which run showing some text in separate eclipse view and automatically manipulating IDE windows providing examples for a student.

I wonder, how is it possible to change the font size in a window showing help text? It is entitled "Task-Focused tutorials". Is it possible to identify view type or something to locate the setting in "Colors and Fonts" section of Eclipse settings gui?